# Where is the right place to put files in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to Laravel and am trying to find my way around.

I want to create multiple custom Exception classes. I am a little confused as to where they should reside.

- Should I create a folder in 'app' and place them in there and include the files manually from global.php?
- Should I create a service provider?

For now, I have created a folder called 'exceptions' in app and added the path to `ClassLoader::addDirectories`. I could really do with some advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using Composer? For example, using Composer you can put your configuration for autoloading:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/database/seeds"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "Exceptions\\": "src/Exceptions",
        "Services\\": "src/Services",
        "Api\\": "src/Api"
    }
},
```

As result your Exception file /src/Exceptions/Specific/ExtraSpecificException.php will be available

```
namespace Exceptions\Specific;


class ExtraSpecificException extends \Exception
{}
```

Answer (score 1):

Laravel doesn't have a set place to store custom exceptions, you can place them anywhere you like.

Creating an app/exceptions/ directory works fine - You can autoload them all in your global.php file by adding

```
app_path() . '/exceptions/'
```

to the ClassLoader::addDirectories array.

If you have a lot and prefer to be more organised you can namespace your exception classes and take advantage of PSR-4 autoloading with composer.

Comment: Yes, I used this approach in the end. Thanks !